# Syntax Error When Trying to Open Downloaded Django Application

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, anaconda, python-3.6

I am trying to work on a Django application that I downloaded from bitbucket which uses Python2-based code. Previously, Python 3.6 and Django 2.0 was on my system, so I downgraded to Python 2.7 and Django 1.11 to try to get it to work.

When I go to the project directory and type in "python manage.py runserver," I get a syntax error (this is a shortened version of it, hence the dots):

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000006A0A358>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  .
  .
  .
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admindocs\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admindocs import views
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admindocs\views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admindocs import utils
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admindocs\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import docutils.core
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docutils\core.py", line 246
    print('\n::: Runtime settings:', file=self._stderr)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you have a solution to this problem, please let me know.

Comment: You've screwed up your Python install(s). Your Python 2 is trying to load Python 3 libraries.

Comment: Docutils have the problem & now fixed this issue ... Ref: https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/bugs/365/

Answer (score 0):

As said by @emi, you want to use virtualenv. It's a great tool that allows you to create an isolated virtual environment for each Python project. Each virtual environment can have its own version of every dependency.

On Windows, I recommend using it alongside [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), witch is is just a very thin wrapper with some higher level commands.

It seems your Python installation is broken so uninstall every version of Python you have, reinstall Python 2 and follow along creating a virtualenv for your project (and for every new one you start). If you need you can install Python 3 in the future as well without messing with you previous envs.